# How to append to an XML response an error attribute using Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, activerecord, response

I am trying to implement REST APIs, so in my RoR3 application I have XML responses. Before to pass to a consumer the XML, I would like to check if there are errors somewhere and, if so, append and send back a response with error messages.

I read "[Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#working-with-validation-errors)" guides on the RoR website, but it seems not work in my case.

I extract from the database a resource doing

```
@response = User.find_by_id(1)
```

and I would like, if possible, to access @response.errors after a "validation".

Seeing some examples I have seen how to report errors in an XML file

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @response.errors }
```

but **how can I add new errors to the @response?**

Maybe something like this:

```
errors.add(:password, "is invalid")
```

Comment: @response.errors.add(:password, "is invalid") does not work?

Comment: Yes! Post the response so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works too:

```
errors.add_to_base('your text')
```

but you should put it in the model.